# Disable column sorting or filtering on report or column

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

New to Jaspersoft reports...

According to this Jaspersoft Community page How to disable [Table sorting/filtering feature (JIVE)](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-disable-table-sortingfiltering-feature-jive-jasperreports-server), Table sorting and filtering can be disabled per report or column.

If so, what are the steps to implement it?

What do I add the property to in the outline? I have tried the Table, the Column Header label, the Detail Text field, etc.

- I right click and choose Show Properties.
- Click Edit Properties from the Properties window.
- Add a new Component Property of
  "net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.column.sortable". or filterable
- Set the value to false.
- Publish the report to Jaspersoft server.
- Refresh the report in Jaspersoft server.
- Filtering and sorting are still enabled.
- Publish the report
- Refresh the Jaspersoft server page
- Filtering and sorting are still enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties needs to be set on the table column node/object itself, and on an element in a column cell/section.  This makes sense from the JasperReports library point of view, but doing it in Jaspersoft Studio is a little awkward.

What you need to do is to open the table in the Outline view, then expand any table section (such as Detail), select the column node under the section (not the element in the column), right click, Show Properties and then in the Properties view go to Advanced and Misc/Edit Properties (which shows a button when you click [Properties]).

This is how it looks like on my machine:

[image: screenshot]

After setting, for instance, the `net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.column.sortable` property to false for a column:

[image]

running the report in JasperReports Server will have sorting disabled for the column:

[image]

Comment: This was very helpful, but filterable and sortable didn't seem to have any impact. When you change them, can you see a difference in Jasper server or with Visualize.js?

Comment: Yes, setting net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.column.sortable and net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.column.filterable worked for me, filtering and sorting got disabled for the column when running the report both in the server UI and via Visualize.js.  I added two more screenshots to the answer.